# Start activity from Uri and Webview

Tags: android, webview

Please, help me.
I need to launch a WebView with special URL. When person fills his login/password, it returns URI myapp://token#access_token=xxxxx and returns to the app

Now I'm not using WebView, but just

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=12345"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

The problem is that all other activities are created from browser, not from my app 
[image]

as you see, main activity is created properly, but the second one belongs to browser.
I know, that using webview can keep all activities in one app, but I don't know how to do all this.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: if you using webview you can access the currentUrl  opened in webview or you can using the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permission to read the history of the opened url and get yours

Comment: see this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/